# how can I edit flexslider in woocommerce. [Urgent]

Tags: functions, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, gallery, production

Can anyone please tell me how I can edit flexslider settings in woocommerce. I am actually trying to get this result. http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html      someone please help me to find this out.. I need it so urgently.

Comment: but the code is in the link you gave

Comment: the js code is in there. But I don't know how I make it work in woocommerce product thumbnails. I can get other slider demo working using this filter woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options but can't get this done. Can you please tell me how I can make this work in woocommerce product thumbnails?

Comment: if it's not already a slider, you'll have to edit the html and js, otherwise just the js. look at the template files.

Comment: if it's a slider already there may be a separate filter for it

Comment: I tried that way and succeeded. But the error here is that when I change variation product while not selecting the featured image then the main image for the variable product doesn't change......